# Is it correct to use "an appointment or appointment?

Tags: grammar

I could not understand, which is correct: **"an appointment"** or just **"appointment"**?

To my understanding, appointment is uncountable noun, and still I found an appointment... an audit etc is used.

Please help me understand the rule.

Comment: It all depends on context. *I have **an** appointment this afternoon,* or *What time is **the** appointment?* require an article, but *You can only see the doctor by appointment* doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. But why do you use an with appointment?

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused with ***disappointment***, which would rarely be considered "countable". But you can certainly have several appointments in one day, for example.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood. Several means no an, and single means an appointment.

Comment: Well, not always. I might want to tell you about ***the three appointments*** that I have next week! The use of articles in English is very complicated, especially for learners who don't have or don't normally use articles in their native language. But you have to ask about *specific* usages here, because *How are articles used in English?* is far too broad for a single question on ELL.

Comment: "Appointment" can also refer to a nonelective office or position, or the act of choosing or being chosen for it.  So it would help to add some context to the question.

Comment: Appointment can be used as an uncountable noun, but it is more commonly used as a countable noun. Can you provide an example or references as to the use you are asking about so that we might be able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Appointment has multiple definitions which vary in their countability.

From [wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/appointment) :

> WordReference Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English © 2019
>
> ap•point•ment /əˈpɔɪntmənt/
> n.
> an agreement for a meeting arranged in advance:
> **[countable]** We made an appointment to meet again.
> **[uncountable]** You can visit the museum by appointment.
>
> *Government* the act of appointing or choosing, as to an office or position:
> **[uncountable]** the appointment of the chairman.
>
> *Government* an office to which a person is appointed:
> **[countable]** an appointment as ambassador.
>
> *Usually,* appointments. [plural] equipment, furnishings, or furniture:
> **[countable]** the handsome appointments of the castle.

You may say "an appointment" when "appointment" is countable, otherwise not.

Comment: Hm, you can also visit the museum by bus, does that make the bus uncountable?